# Laravel /. Mongodb - fatal error: 'pcre2.h' file not found

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to install mongodb using this command on my macbook pro m1 laptop.

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

But I got this error message:

> In file included from
> /private/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/MongoDB/Cursor.c:18: In file
> included from
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.15/include/php/ext/spl/spl_iterators.h:22:
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.15/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:23:10:
> fatal error: 'pcre2.h' file not found
> #include "pcre2.h"
> ^~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated. make: *** [src/MongoDB/Cursor.lo] Error 1 ERROR: `make' failed

Can you please tell me how can I fix this?

Comment: You need to install some missing libraries and reinstall by : `brew install pcre2` and `brew link --overwrite pcre2` and `sudo pecl install mongodb` and `brew install php-mongodb`.

Comment: Well, I just manually copy the pcre2 file to the desire directory and it's working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way to fix this that I've outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73444451/3959933. Instead of running `sudo pecl install mongodb` run the following:

```
CFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/include sudo pecl install mongodb
```

This will ensure that the compiler also checks `/opt/homebrew/include` to find the correct include files.